# Oracle query eliminate duplicates not considering Null

Tags: sql, oracle

I've performed a full outer join where I get the following:

```
ColumnFromTable1          ColumnFromTable2
     AAA                       ABA
     AAA                       Null          <-  remove
     AAA                       ACC
     BBB                       Null
     CCC                       CDC
     Null                      EFE
     DDD                       FFF
     Null                      FFF           <-  remove
     GGG                       FFF
```

What I really want is to squash down the rows to remove duplicates such that my results would be:

```
ColumnFromTable1          ColumnFromTable2
     AAA                       ABA
     AAA                       ACC
     BBB                       Null
     CCC                       CDC
     Null                      EFE
     DDD                       FFF
     GGG                       FFF
```

Basically I need to eliminate

```
AAA  Null
Null  FFF
```

since I have an AAA or FFF with a non-null. But I need to keep

```
BBB  Null
Null  EFE
```

because there is no BBB or EFE with a non-null

I've tried modifying my full outer join (which I can post if need be) and also tried wrapping these results in a sub query.

**EDIT** here is the query simplified for this post

```
select ColumnFromTable1, ColumnFromTable2 from Table1 t1
       full outer join Table2 t2 on t1.common_code = t2.common_code 
       group by ColumnFromTable1, ColumnFromTable2
```

Comment: can you please post your query here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`row_number()` looks promising:

```
select c1, c2
  from (
    select c1, c2, 
           row_number() over (partition by c1 order by c2) r1,
           row_number() over (partition by c2 order by c1) r2
      from t)
  where not ((c1 is null and r2 > 1) or (c2 is null and r1 > 1))
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=62a4bcc1c816d4b16d4c216e43fa87b9)</sup>**

It eliminates null values when they are not first in order.

Comment: This worked and was easy to implement with my existing JPA query.  The fiddle demo helped as it is not clear from the post itself that I needed to use "with t(c1, c2) as (" then my original query)

Answer (score 0):

Placing the full outer join you already computed in a CTE, you can filter it further as you want by doing:

```
with f (c1, c2) as (
  ... -- full outer join you already computed here
)
a (x) as ( -- repeated c1 with non-null c2
  select c1
  from f
  group by c1
  having count(c2) > 0
),
b (x) as ( -- repeated c2 with non-null c1
  select c2
  from f
  group by c2
  having count(c1) > 0
)
select *
from f
where not(c1 in (select x from a) and c2 is null)
  and not(c2 in (select x from b) and c1 is null)
```